# Cast json in to Map<String,Map<String,String>> Format

Tags: dart, flutter

I need to convert the json string to nested Map and access the same.

Following Json String is in form of Map given below

```
Map<String,Map<String,String>> 

{"0":{"1551874690005":"2","1551874722124":"2","1551874810817":"2","1551874681110":"2","1551874739821":"2","1551874763604":"2","1551874692381":"2","1551874816028":"2","1551874708292":"2","1551874804308":"2","1551874694205":"2","1551874696644":"2","1551874729332":"2","1551874749950":"2","1551874767786":"2"},"1":{"1551948649643":"0","1551948733576":"0","1551948601167":"0","1551948592816":"0","1551948699297":"0","1551874822043":"2","1551948681513":"0","1551948531568":"0","1551948577374":"0","1551948719758":"0","1552370125650":"0","1551948549863":"0","1551948564519":"0","1551948631000":"0","1551953956716":"0"},"2":{"1551875011432":"0","1551875020618":"0","1551874991952":"0","1551875091300":"0","1551875073622":"0","1551875032851":"0","1551874827691":"0","1551948658122":"0","1551874846523":"0","null":"0","1552545417127":"0","1551875083856":"0","1551874929076":"0","1552545972738":"0"},"3":{"1552651031695":"0"},"4":{"1551875144268":"0","1551875157028":"0","1551875115211":"0","1551875124660":"0"}}
```

**Getting following error while trying using my code:**

```
Unhandled Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, String>' in type cast
```

```
Map offlineExeStatus = jsonDecode(prefs.getString("offlineExeStatus"));

Map<String,Map<String,String>> exeStatusFinalJson = new Map();

exeStatusFinalJson = offlineExeStatus.cast<String,Map<String,String>();
```

**Need to cast the given json in "exeStatusFinalJson" Map and access like:
exeStatusFinalJson["0"] should give the output like:**

```
{"1551874690005":"2","1551874722124":"2","1551874810817":"2","1551874681110":"2","1551874739821":"2","1551874763604":"2","1551874692381":"2","1551874816028":"2","1551874708292":"2","1551874804308":"2","1551874694205":"2","1551874696644":"2","1551874729332":"2","1551874749950":"2","1551874767786":"2"}
```

Comment: https://app.quicktype.io/

Comment: Yes @primo, I tried converting it in class but it will be **n** number of recorder under key "0", "1", etc... need a casting operation for this.

Comment: ok so it is a api response?

Comment: Nope, Actually I'm using it as to maintain the status for offline feature. I'm stuck in this because of the nested Map.

Comment: how is this json generated?

Comment: I'm generating it, ```tempExe[key] = "0/1/2";   Constants.exeStatusComp[i.toString()] = tempExe;```  Here tempExe is Map and exeStatusComp is outer Map.

Comment: Yes nice, Appreciated your help. @primo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured out the way to do it!

```
Map offlineExeStatus = jsonDecode(prefs.getString("onlineExeStatus"));

Map<String, dynamic> exeStatusJson = new Map();

Map<String, Map<String, String>> exeStatusFinalJson = new Map();

List<String> mapKeyExe = new List();

mapKeyExe = offlineExeStatus.keys.cast<String>().toList();

exeStatusJson = offlineExeStatus.cast<String, dynamic>();

for (int i = 0; i < mapKeyExe.length; i++) {
    Map<String, String> exeStatusInsideJson = new Map();

    exeStatusInsideJson = offlineExeStatus[mapKeyExe[i].toString()]
       .cast<String, String>();

    exeStatusFinalJson[i.toString()] = exeStatusInsideJson;

    print(exeStatusFinalJson);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to declare your map as `Map<String, dynamic>` rather than `Map<String, Map<String, String>>`.

Comment: ```jsonDecode(prefs.getString("offlineExeStatus"));``` this will come in form of ```Map<String, dynamic>``` but I want it in ```Map<String, Map<String, String>>```

Comment: You can have the structure of `Map<String, Map<String, String>>` by declaring is as a `Map<String, dynamic>`.  `dynamic` means it can be of all types. Does it result in any troubles or why are you so eager to declare it explicitly as a `Map<String, Map<String, String>>`?

Comment: @AbhiShah, are you making any progress on this issue?